# lando gets its mysql database docker service killed with no error

Tags: docker, lando

I have a lando service for my WordPress development. It's mainly a LAMP that uses a mariaDB container for the database.

After starting the lando app, and at random intervals 5 minutes, an hour, the docker mariaDB container gets killed and I can't find any error on the docker container log.

If I run `docker logs` with the database container id I get:

```
2021-03-30T09:43:33.099754Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2021-03-30T09:43:33.101884Z 0 [Note] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.29'  socket: '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
/launch.sh: line 11:    38 Killed                  /opt/bitnami/scripts/mysql/entrypoint.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/mysql/run.sh
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot that further. I was not doing anything out of the ordinary at the moment. Not big queries nor big loads in any way. If I do `lando stop && lando start` the database works again but it eventually fails again.

One curious thing I noted is that if I do `lando info` before and after the database crushing I get this:

Before:

```
  { service: 'database',
    urls: [],
    type: 'mysql',
    healthy: true,
    internal_connection: { host: 'database', port: '3306' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: '51771' },
    healthcheck: 'bash -c "[ -f /bitnami/mysql/.mysql_initialized ]"',
    creds: { database: 'wordpress', password: 'wordpress', user: 'wordpress' },
```

After:

```
{ service: 'database',
    urls: [],
    type: 'mysql',
    healthy: true,
    internal_connection: { host: 'database', port: '3306' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: true },
    healthcheck: 'bash -c "[ -f /bitnami/mysql/.mysql_initialized ]"',
    creds: { database: 'wordpress', password: 'wordpress', user: 'wordpress' },
```

Note the port changes from a random port (51771) expected, to "true"

Is there any other log I can check?
What is causing my database to get killed?

Thanks

Comment: Can you point to the images/dockerfiles you used?

Comment: I'm using lando that, as far as I know, automates the part that usually a dockerfile would automate. Not sure if it does create a dockerfile (I can't find that) or if it just skips it.
I'm using lando's WordPress recipe: https://docs.lando.dev/config/wordpress.html

Comment: Did you check with lando logs? https://docs.lando.dev/basics/logs.html#logs